# Debian 10: mdadm raid superblocks "dissappear" after reboot?

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm

I'm very confused by some issues I'm having with a raid setup with mdadm.

I have a Debian 10 system, which I installed a KVM VM on, to use as a NAS server. I had problems with the raid superblocks dissappearing when rebooting, and never got to the bottom of the issue, so I started doing some more tests today, without the VM.

I tried to create a raid 1 array with mdadm on the host system. (Not on a VM)

I then rebooted the system, and again the raid superblocks appear to have dissappeared or somehow been wiped blank?

The system is using a LSI pci-e SAS card, flashed in IT mode, with a few 1TB Toshiba SATA drives.

Anyway, here's a list of commands run from this morning...

```
  184  sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
  185  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/md0
  188  cat /proc/mdstat
```

At this point the raid finishes initializing

```
  189  sudo update-initramfs -u
  190  sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
  191  cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Seems ok

```
  193  echo '/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab 
  194  sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/md0
```

Can read data on drives ok, still there from last raid configuration

```
  195  cat /proc/mdstat
```

... reboot, no `md0` device started or mounted

```
  197  sudo mdadm --detail --scan
```

blank!

```
  198  cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
  199  cat /proc/mdstat
```

blank!

```
  200  sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

does nothing

I'm extremely confused by what is going on here - and I have no clue how to start diagnosing the problem further.

Comment: You updated your  initramfs **before** generating a new `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf ` - but you likely want to assemble your array with just initramfs data available, so you need to update your initramfs **after** writing the new config, to have it included there!

Comment: Always use the `--verbose` flag to see which devices were scanned, that should help distinguish between bad config, bad superblock and devices skipped.

Comment: @anx `mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose` gives "no RAID superblock on /dev/sdblaablaa (Expected magic blaablaa got <something different>`

Comment: @anx Is the `update-initramfs -u` required? What does this step actually do, I've not quite understood it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to complete that output? I would find it rather odd if `--scan` only reported about one out of two disks. In any case, if you think these disks already were synced once, wouldnt hurt to check whats IS contained in that sector. Zeroes, a bootloader, ..?

Comment: Never really got to the bottom of this. Blanking discs with `dd if=/dev/zero` *may* have been part of the solution. It may have also helped to use `wipefs` to remove superblocks.